# How to make denial of the list of items?

Tags: python, arrays, set

I have the list with some values, i want to exclude **not** the values from my list and replace them with 0.

That is pseudocode:

```
for i in range(0,img.shape[0]):
for j in range(0,img.shape[1]):
    if img[i][j]!=[some values]:
        img[i][j]=0
```

Comment: Pretty much yeah. But `!=` should be `not in` instead.

Comment: @LennartRegebro ahahahahah thanks, i didn't know about it))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
In [1]: l = [1, 2, 1, 10, 2, 1, 3, 10]

In [2]: exclusions = [1, 2]

In [3]: [el if el not in exclusions else 0 for el in l]
Out[3]: [0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 3, 10]
```

Depending on the size of `exclusions`, the code might be more performant if you turned it into a `set`.

Comment: How it looks in the case of the set?

Comment: @HenryKolesnik: `exclusions = set([1, 2])`. Everything else is exactly the same.